# WPF TabItem design problems on windows 7 (Windows 98 theme)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need some help to do the icons fit better on this old theme. 
As you can see the icons on this old theme are being cut by any reason that I don't know. Please help me. It must not be hard to fix. Thanks

XAML code that I am using:

```
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Grid x:Name="grid"  ToolTip="(F1) Calculadora de datas" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Image x:Name="image" Source="Images/Central/TabIcons/date_icon.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="36" Width="36"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_dayTab" Content="day" Margin="4,10,5.782,5.145" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem.Header>
```

[image: Problem picture (Old theme with problem and how it should be)]

Comment: have you tried removing width and height from Image.

Comment: Plop them in a ViewBox.